# How to paste factor labels conditionally in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, concatenation, paste

Hope someone can help me on this one for which I have just found a lousy solution on my own: I would like to aggregate (or paste) the labels of four columns (`A` to `D`) into a fifth (`dream`) but conditionally, that is only if its numeric value is 2.

Here is my database `df`:

```
id= c(1:12)
A = c(2,NA,NA,2,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,2)
B = c(2,1,1,1,2,NA,1,1,1,1,2,1)
C = c(2,1,1,1,2,NA,1,1,1,1,NA,1)
D = c(2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,NA,2,1)
df = data.frame(id,A,B,C,D) ; df
df$A=factor(df$A, labels=c("no", "i saw"))
df$B=factor(df$B, labels=c("no", "someone"))
df$C=factor(df$C, labels=c("no", "sitting"))
df$D=factor(df$D, labels=c("no", "on a cloud")) ; df
```

Here is below the solution i found, but not so satisfying...

```
df$dream = ifelse(as.numeric(df$A)!=2, NA, as.character(df$A)) ; df
df$dream = ifelse(as.numeric(df$B)!=2, df$dream, paste(df$dream, as.character(df$B))) ; df
df$dream = ifelse(as.numeric(df$C)!=2, df$dream, paste(df$dream, as.character(df$C))) ; df
df$dream = ifelse(as.numeric(df$D)!=2, df$dream, paste(df$dream, as.character(df$D))) ; df
```

I am sure there is a straightfoward way to do so, in addition my code doesn't even seem to work this way.. Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Not to be trivial but have you considered changing the label from "no" to ""?

Comment: i am not sure this would help for the problem i have , Elin. I you try my code above you will see it is not about having "no" or not as a label, i believe it is rather a more general problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work but you have to declare this vector of values you want to paste from factors.

```
# init empty result vector
dream <- character(nrow(df))
# values from each column (A-D) you want to paste
values <- c("i saw","someone","sitting", "on a cloud")
# iterate over each row
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  #paste values from each row
  dream[i] <- paste(values[which(as.numeric(df[i,-1]) == 2)], collapse=" ")  
}
```

Comment: It works indeed very well, thanks. But i still have to understand how this works... and why `-1`in expression `df[i,-1]`. But this is exactly what i needed !

Comment: The '-1' removes the first element of a vector (which is 'id' column)

Comment: Great, Thanks +++ i got it. Do you know why using `dream[i] <- paste((values[which(as.numeric(df[i,-c(1,6]) == 2)], collapse=" "), df[i,6])` does not work if i just wanted to paste one last attribut from a 6th column ?

Comment: Looks like you've got brackets wrong. `df[i,6]` goes before `collapse`

Comment: Indeed but i also tried ` dream[i] <- paste((values[which(as.numeric(df[i,-c(1,6)]) == 2)], df[i,6]), collapse=" ") ` and still, it does not work... i get `unexpected ',' in:
"for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
dream[i] <- paste((values[which(as.numeric(df[i,-c(1,6)]) == 2)]," ` and i dont understand...

Comment: I actually discussed an elegant and efficient solution which is finally my favourite one (for this last objective i had yesterday): `for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
                df$dream[i] <- paste(paste(df[i,c("A","B","C")][df[i,c("A","B","C")]!="no" & !is.na(df[i,c("A","B","C")])],sep=" ",collapse=" "),
                                                                                                              df[i,"D"][!is.na(df[i,"D"])],sep=" ",collapse=" ")
}
` The use of `paste(paste(...` does the trick. Thanks again @bartektartanus

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier if you transform you `data.frame` in `data.table`.

For `column B` you can use

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[,dream:=ifelse(B==2,"someone",ifelse(B==1,"no",NA))]
```

And then replicate the same for the rest `3 columns`. I hope this helps

**UPDATE**

Or maybe you could try this

```
dt$dream.A <- mapvalues(dt$A,c(1,2),c("no", "i saw"))
```

Comment: Thanks, @quant. This may work but the answer before would be the one i would go for, because it is a short function.